# Android - `main` module field for "react-native-gesture-handler" lib that could not be resolved in Azure CI & its working fine in local machine

Tags: react-native, android-studio, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, macos-big-sur

I am working with the azure pipeline for CICD for React native app. I am using **macOS Big Sur** (11.4) and Android Studio 4.2.2 as a local machine to create and test the app. App working fine on the local machine without any warning or issue. However, when I am pushing the code on the Azure pipeline it is giving me errors as below,

```
  * /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/src/index.ts/index(.native|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json).
Error: While trying to resolve module `react-native-gesture-handler` from file `/Users/runner/work/1/s/index.js`, the package `/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/src/index.ts`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

  * /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/src/index.ts(.native|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  * /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/src/index.ts/index(.native|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:436:17)
    at Object.resolve (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:317:42)
    at resolve (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:629:33)
    at /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:645:26
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:644:33)
    at /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:329:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:137:24)
    at _next (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:159:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

> Task :app:bundleMasterReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
> Task :app:mergeUatDebugResources

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

My observation is that the Azure pipeline does not have macOS Big Sur as Agent. My local machine changes some configurations to support the latest Android studio and macOS and the azure pipeline agent does not support macOS Big Sur reason it is not able to find it

[image].

NOTE: I have tried all clean processes like yarn, pod, or delete node_module.

[azure-devops]

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution for the issue.

Actually, the latest version of macOS Big Sur (11.4) was not having a node install on VM.

I did some changes in the pipeline.

```
pool:
  vmImage: macOS-11

steps:

- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
  clean: true

- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: 'Install Node'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 'v16.6.2' # you can use your desired version here

- script: yarn install
  displayName: Install Dependencies
```