# React Native pipeline android build failed : Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'

Tags: react-native, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I tried to build an app using the GitLab pipeline and it failed with the following error

```
Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
```

But the app is built locally without any error. Can anyone have an idea why this happened?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Basically, your local machine and virtual machine on DevOps have different configurations. I solved it by updating the node and latest VM on azure DevOps. You can update your YAML file with the below code and change the node to the latest version available.

Please follow this solution: [Android - `main` module field for "react-native-gesture-handler" lib that could not be resolved in Azure CI & its working fine in local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68545740/android-main-module-field-for-react-native-gesture-handler-lib-that-could)

Please refer to the link from the Azure DevOps team for the latest mac os, Xcode, and node available. Cross-check with your local machine

https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/macos/macos-11-Readme.md